# Question on comparative constructions

Tags: comparative-constructions

Which of the following is *preferred*? Please let me know if the answer varies between spoken and written English.

1- The death rates for women are lower than men at all ages.

2- The death rates for women are lower than **those** for men at all ages.

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *The death rates for women are lower than men at all ages*
> 2: *The death rates for women are lower than **those for** men at all ages*
> 3: *The death rates for women are lower than **for** men at all ages*
> 4: *The death rates for women are lower than **they are for** men at all ages*

All 4 versions are fine, and mean *exactly* the same thing - as do another 4 without the initial definite article ***The***. Come to that, there are another 4 with singular *The **death rate** for women **is** lower than...* (and ***that*** for ***those***, ***it is*** for ***they are***) that also mean exactly the same.

I don't think there's much point in trying to establish which of these 12 alternatives is the most common. Just accept them all as "valid equivalents", and if you need to write anything like that yourself, choose whichever you like best. Spoken / written, formal / informal are not relevant factors here.

---

I may be going out on a limb here, but I think there are another 3 alternatives based on changing the second instance of preposition ***for*** in example #2 to ***of***...

> 2a: *The death rates for women are lower than **those of** men at all ages*

...where it *isn't* idiomatic to make that preposition switch with the other three "base" examples.

Comment: I must disagree about #1. OP specifically asked about writing. A careful editor would never let this one slide, and a teacher might jump on it as well. They would assert that the sentence compares "rates" with "men" and call such a comparison meaningless. Many test questions are designed to catch this exact point.

Comment: That sounds more like "over-zealous pedant" than "careful editor" to me. But everyone's entitled to an opinion, I guess.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers for the insights. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyCarney for providing the valuable grammar tip!